# Spark DataFrame Union Recursion

Tags: scala, apache-spark, recursion, apache-spark-sql, tail-recursion

I am trying to substring(column,numOne,numTwo) for a given original DataFrame and create a new DataFrame by doing UNION on all subsets of DataFrame which were being created by doing substring(column,numOne,numTwo).
Below is some piece of code I've come up with

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    //To Log only ERRORS
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("PopularMoviesDS")
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/temp")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

    var swing = 2
    val dataframeInt = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
      (1, "Chandler", "Pasadena", "US")
    )).toDF("id", "name", "city", "country")
    var returnDf:DataFrame = spark.emptyDataFrame.withColumn("name",functions.lit(null))
    def dataFrameCreatorOrg(df:DataFrame): DataFrame ={
      val map:Map[Int, Seq[String]] = Map(1 -> Seq("1","4"), 2 -> Seq("2","5"))
        var returnDf:DataFrame = spark.emptyDataFrame.withColumn("name",functions.lit(null))
      while(swing>0){
        returnDf =  returnDf.union(df.selectExpr(s"substring(name,${map(swing)(0)},${map(swing)(1)})"))
        swing -= 1
      }
      returnDf
    }
dataFrameCreator(dataframeInt).show()
    +-----+
    | name|
    +-----+
    |handl|
    | Chan|
    +-----+
```

The above code is working as I expected, but I want to run the above-using tail recursion. Code below,

```
    var swing = 2
    val dataframeInt = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
      (1, "Chandler", "Pasadena", "US")
    )).toDF("id", "name", "city", "country")
    var returnDf:DataFrame = spark.emptyDataFrame.withColumn("name",functions.lit(null))

    def dataFrameCreator(df:DataFrame): DataFrame ={
      val map:Map[Int, Seq[String]] = Map(1 -> Seq("1","4"), 2 -> Seq("2","5"))
      returnDf = returnDf.union(df.selectExpr(s"substring(name,${map(swing)(0)},${map(swing)(1)})"))
      returnDf
    }

    @tailrec
    def bigUnionHelper(num: Int, df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
      if (num<0) df
      else bigUnionHelper(num-1, dataFrameCreator(dataframeInt))
    }
    bigUnionHelper(swing, dataframeInt).show()
//Result:
+-----+
| name|
+-----+
|handl|
|handl|
|handl|
+-----+
```

I totally get that there is room for optimization but I am unable to figure out why the tailRecursive - bigUnionHelper is not working and not giving the same result as the first function.
Any help is appreciated, Thank you so much in Advance.

Comment: Without having too much time looking at the code. Spark is horrible at horizontal cataloging. Try interimDF  = union logic and the next line be returnDF = interimDF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be this way.

```
val swing = 2
val dataframeInt = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
    (1, "Chandler", "Pasadena", "US")
)).toDF("id", "name", "city", "country")

def bigUnionHelper(df: DataFrame, num: Int): DataFrame = {
    @tailrec
    def dataFrameCreator(df: DataFrame, num:Int, acc:List[DataFrame] = List()): List[DataFrame] = {
        if (num < 1) acc
        else {
            val map: Map[Int, Seq[String]] = Map(1 -> Seq("1", "4"), 2 -> Seq("2", "5"))
            val tempDf = df.selectExpr(s"substring(name,${map(num).head},${map(swing)(1)})")
            dataFrameCreator(df, num -1, tempDf :: acc)
        }
    }
    dataFrameCreator(df, num).reduce(_ union _)
}

bigUnionHelper(dataframeInt, swing).show()
```

Comment: Awesome! It's Working, Thank you Gorros. I am going to check what mistake I've made now.